# How do I stop daemonized OpenVPN connection?

Tags: command-line, openvpn, daemon

I started a VPN connection with `sudo openvpn --daemon --config connection.ovpn`. Is there a way to terminate this connection without using `ps` to search for the process and then `kill` it myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since OpenVPN does not seem to offer any function of its own for this, you are probably looking for `pkill <process-name>`, which will search for *all* processes matching the given name, and kill them.

If you got multiple instances running, but would like to kill only a specific one, the `-f` option allows you to match against the full process-call including parameters, e.g. `pkill -f "openvpn --config connection.ovpn"`.

See the output from `ps x` or `pgrep -lf <process-name>` (same as `pkill`, but doesn't kill them, so essentially similar to `ps | grep <name>`) to find out with which parameters the daemon was started.

Answer (score 4):

From https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/

Controlling a running OpenVPN processRunning on Linux/BSD/Unix

OpenVPN accepts several signals:

```
SIGUSR1 — Conditional restart, designed to restart without root privileges
SIGHUP — Hard restart
SIGUSR2 — Output connection statistics to log file or syslog
SIGTERM, SIGINT — Exit
```

Use the writepid directive to write the OpenVPN daemon’s PID to a file, so that you know where to send the signal (if you are starting openvpn with an initscript, the script may already be passing a –writepid directive on the openvpn command line).

So , you should use kill command, and start openvpn with arg -writepid.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will need to kill the process. In fairness a daemon management script would do just that. You can use pgrep or pkill to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --config $'client'.ovpn
```

Replace client with the corresponding name.
This will shutdown the session.